# Starting word of the sentence not printed using c programming language

Tags: c, string, printf

when I am trying to concatenate a word and a sentence the first word of the sentence automatically deleted, what improvement should I use.. my code is: enter code here`

```
char word[]="AddMe";
char adder[150];
// reading string from stdin
scanf("%[^\n]*c",%sentence);
strcat(adder,word);
strcat(adder,sentence);
puts(adder);
```

Comment: can you repost the code, scanf("%[^\n]*c",%sentence); wont compile

Comment: `char sentence[100]; scanf("%99[^\n]%*c", sentence); strcpy(adder, word); strcat(adder, sentence);`

Answer (score 0):

First, use:

```
strcpy(adder,word);
```